# How to use href for sending attributes and linking to id at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do redirecting login.

I have this a

```
<div class="custombtn1 right25"><a class="modal_trigger" href="#modal"></a></div>
```

that links to an id #modal (opens login popup), but I want to add parameter that says witch of 3 links was clicked so I can direct user to link he actually clicked.

Comment: I tryied to do it like href="#modal?clikpage='election' "> but it ruined the popup.

Comment: `#modal` would have to go at the end of the URL after the query parameters.

Comment: tried href="index.php?clickpage=election.php#modal" popup didnt show up

Comment: What code is it that opens the popup?

Comment: This should be the js part $(".modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" }); 

and this is div it opens <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;"></div>

Comment: but seems that in leanModal.js has this line $(this).click(function(e){var modal_id=$(this).attr("href"); maby this is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is just one of many ways you could do it. Yet, without more information it's impossible to know what method would work best for your application.

**Example: Run the code snippet to test.**

```html
<div class="custombtn1 right25"><a class="modal_trigger" href="#modal"></a></div>

<html>
  <body>
    
    
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#modal" onclick="login(this, 1)">Login 1</a>
    <li><a href="#modal" onclick="login(this, 2)">Login 2</a>
    <li><a href="#modal" onclick="login(this, 3)">Login 3</a>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="login"></div>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // add popup login here
      function login( obj, n ) {
        document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = (
          '<div style="padding:10px;border:1px steelblue solid;background-color: silver;">'+
          '<div>You clicked: ' + obj.href + ' number ' + n + '</div><br>'+
          'Name:<input type="text"> Password:<input type="password">'+
          '</div>'
       );
        
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't help in my case, but it gave me idea how to do it. Thanks :)